# blender compositing - 2d motion blur when using a transform node?

Tags: compositing-nodes, 2d, motion-blur

I am attempting to use the blender compositor and am adding a post move of a camera shake to my plate/cg composite.

If I were using a simple 'transform' and/or 'rotate' node within the compositor, how do you apply a 2d motionblur to this?

my node graph looks like so:

[image]

and I ask, as in nuke, it's as simple as ticking a box:
[image]

Any tips appreciated,

Cheers!

Comment: why don't you use the blur node?

Comment: Heya!  Could you expand on this?

The blur node doesn't seem to provide the motion steps of a camera shutter open/close, but rather an overall gaussian blur.  

I'd love to be proven wrong though!

Comment: I'm not sure it exists in Blender, there is the Vector Blur but it takes into account the movement in your scene, not the movement in an image sequence

Comment: @jerry-nz: i wrote an answer, how i meant it ;)

Answer (score 0):

i have made a very (!) simple setup, be aware that you might have to change some indices values to get the same result.

My idea is to subtract the transform value form the current frame from the value of the frame before.

so this: t(f) - t(f-1)

you can get a value from an fcurve like this:

```
bpy.data.actions[0].fcurves[0].evaluate(frame)
```

so it is very easy to get the value from the frame before:

```
bpy.data.actions[0].fcurves[0].evaluate(frame-1)
```

so i set this value as driver in the blur node:

[image]

[image]

```
(bpy.data.actions[0].fcurves[0].evaluate(frame)-bpy.data.actions[0].fcurves[0].evaluate(frame-1))*20
```

of course you have to multiply it with a factor (be aware: The value in the blur node does only take integers). Or you change the strength of your noise (i used a noise fcurve to animate the transform value).

I just did it with the x value here (because i am lazy), but you could add another driver for y and z if you want to, and of course for rotation as well.

[image]

And this is my result for just (!) x driver:

[image]